# ES6 + Babel: Getting TypeError: actions.helloOne() is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I started building a React app (ejected create-react-app) with webpack and babel. However I'm unable to import an external .js file with utility functions.

Whenever I try to call `actions.helloOne()` I get the following error: `TypeError: actions.helloOne is not a function`.

I'm still quite new to JS so I might be missing something obvious.

**helloActions.js**

```
export function helloOne() {
  console.log('one')
}
export function helloTwo() {
  console.log('two')
}
```

**actions.js**

```
import { helloOne, helloTwo } from './helloActions'

export {
  helloOne,
  helloTwo
}
```

**service.js**

```
import * as actions from './actions'

actions.helloOne(); <-   undefined
```

**package.json**

```
"babel-core": "6.22.1",
"babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
"babel-jest": "18.0.0",
"babel-loader": "6.2.10",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^2.2.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "6.5.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy":"1.3.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.11.5",
...
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "react-app",
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy","transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Comment: `import * as actions`? why not `import actions`?

Comment: That's weird. It's working fine for me.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yeah, it seems 100% correct to me, all other examples are the same too. Could it be a bad version on babel or something else?

Comment: Is that all your code? I just tested that code with the ES2015 preset and the latest Babel and it worked fine.

Comment: That's pretty much it. There is more but I am not interacting with it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem, the code was correct as **Andrew Li** mentioned.

I had a slight mistake in the path to one of the files in the import line (basically missed .js at the end which was causing babel to do weird things without throwing an error).